# Oracle Convert TIMESTAMP with Timezone to DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I have DB with timezone `+04:00 (Europe/Moscow)` and need to convert a string in format `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM` to `DATE` data type in Oracle 11g.

In other words, I have a string `2013-11-08T10:11:31+02:00` and I want to convert it to `DATE` data type (in local DB timezone `+04:00 (Europe/Moscow)`).

For string `2013-11-08T10:11:31+02:00` my desired transformation should return `DATE` data type with date `2013-11-08 12:11:31` (i.e. with local timezone transformation of time to `+04:00 (Europe/Moscow)`). Timezone of string may be different and `+02:00` in string above is just example.

I tried to do this with `TIMESTAMP` data type, but no success with time zone transformation.

Comment: Except for situations that need 'local' times (ie, scheduling/planning, especially for timezones with daylight savings), it's usually best to store absolute timestamps stored in UTC (and translate on display/report).  What are these timestamps being used for?

Comment: I receive date in this timestamp format from external system and do not know why external system uses them. :(

Comment: Found my answer.. but in case if you want to double check that timestamp is true or false, I found a good site for this. http://onlinetimestampconvert.com

Answer (score 17):

`to_timestamp_tz()` function with `at time zone` clause can be used to convert your string literal to a value of `timestamp with time zone` data type:

```
SQL> with t1(tm) as(
  2    select '2013-11-08T10:11:31+02:00' from dual
  3  )
  4  select to_timestamp_tz(tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM')
  5           at time zone '+4:00'         as this_way
  6       , to_timestamp_tz(tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM')
  7           at time zone 'Europe/Moscow' as or_this_way
  8    from t1
  9  /
```

Result:

```
THIS_WAY                            OR_THIS_WAY
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-11-08 12.11.31 PM +04:00       2013-11-08 12.11.31 PM EUROPE/MOSCOW
```

And then, we use `cast()` function to produce a value of `date` data type:

```
with t1(tm) as(
  select '2013-11-08T10:11:31+02:00' from dual
)
select cast(to_timestamp_tz(tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') 
         at time zone '+4:00' as date)   as this_way  
     , cast(to_timestamp_tz(tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') 
         at time zone 'Europe/Moscow' as date) as or_this_way
  from t1

This_Way             Or_This_Way 
------------------------------------------
2013-11-08 12:11:31  2013-11-08 12:11:31
```

Find out more about [at time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699) clause and [to_timestamp_tz()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions214.htm#SQLRF06143) function.

Comment: Thank you! `select CAST(to_timestamp_tz('2013-11-08T10:11:31+02:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') at time zone DBTIMEZONE AS DATE) from dual` will be correct way for me

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT
CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(timezonefield AS TIMESTAMP),'GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'CET') AS DATE) 
FROM table;
```

Converts a timestamp in GMT to date in Central European time

Answer (score 2):

if you want your timestamp with timezone to convert to a date in sync with "sysdate" then use the following:

```
select cast(to_timestamp_tz('2013-11-08T10:11:31-02:00'
                           ,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:tzm'
                           ) 
            at time zone to_char(systimestamp
                                ,'tzh:tzm'
                                ) 
            as date
           )
from dual
```

Comment: I cannot tell you how long I searched for some way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

to cast time stamp to date :

cast(registrationmaster.Stamp5DateTime as date) >= '05-05-2018' AND 
cast(registrationmaster.Stamp5DateTime as date) <= '05-05-2018'

Answer (score 0):

you can manage timezones with CAST(x AT TIME ZONE 'YYYY' AS DATE), this helps me:

```
WITH t1 (tm) AS (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-12-14 15:33:00 EET' FROM DUAL)

SELECT 'EET' tz, CAST (tm AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Kaliningrad' AS DATE) AS datetime FROM t1
union SELECT 'MSK' tz, CAST (tm AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow' AS DATE) AS datetime FROM t1
union SELECT 'CET' tz, CAST (tm AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Prague' AS DATE) AS datetime FROM t1
union SELECT 'UTC' tz, CAST (tm AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) AS datetime FROM t1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)