# Date query giving two results in sqlplus & oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have following data in oracle 11g. The datatype of Date is Timestamp(6) with Timezone.

```
  Id         Date

2184597 25-SEP-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM -07:00
2168003 03-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2179370 03-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2187826 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2198078 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2198080 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
```

Now I want to find out all the records whose date is greater than 25-SEP-15. I am using the following query

```
select id,date from tableName  where (date>=TO_DATE('2015-09-25' , 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

I am getting strange results when I am firing the query from sqlplus client and oracle sql developer

In sqlplus client I am getting

```
    2168003 03-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
    2179370 03-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
    2187826 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
    2198078 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
    2198080 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
```

In Oracle sqldeveloper I am getting

```
2184597 25-SEP-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM -07:00
2168003 03-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2179370 03-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2187826 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2198078 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
2198080 11-NOV-04 12.00.00.000000000 AM -08:00
```

Ideally I should only get one record. But I am not sure if this has to do with timezone and how can I rectify it.

Comment: What's the type of the Date column?

Comment: It is Timestamp(6) with Timezone

Comment: why is that a problem?

Comment: u say: where (date>=TO_DATE('2015-09-25' , 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

Comment: which means all result which greater than or equal 2015-09-25 00:00:00. I think 25-SEP-15 with 7 AM is fit

Comment: u didnt define ordering so oracle returns the data randomly

Comment: @Thomas yes. Only one record is fit but we are seeing it brings all the records. I have a feeling it is not taking year into consideration or it has to do something with timezone

Comment: you could try the following in the where: to_timestamp_tz(tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM')

Comment: i suppose the to_date is not enough

Comment: @Thomas you are right. I tried select id ,date from tableName  where (to_char(date, 'dd-MON-yy')>=TO_DATE('25-SEP-14' , 'dd-MON-yy')); Adding to_char to date gives me proper results. Is it correct way to go?

Comment: maybe you could check that answer too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089859/oracle-convert-timestamp-with-timezone-to-date

Comment: there is a cast function too, i think u need define the timezone too in the where condition with those funcs

Comment: Are both your clients configured to use the _same_ timezone? Could you query [SESSIONTIMEZONE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions143.htm) both from SQL*Plus and SQLDeveloper ?

Comment: @Thomas The Cast did the trick. Upvoting your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're comparing two different datatypes in your where clause. In your query, the field date is not DATE I presume. It is either DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

To overcome the problem, use to_date on both sides in the where clause as below.

select id,date from tableName  where TO_DATE(date,'yyyy-MM-dd')>=TO_DATE('2015-09-25' , 'yyyy-MM-dd');

Hope this helps !!