# convert timestamp varchar2 to date datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help converting a Timestamp as `varchar2` to a `date` datatype.

Example (as varchar2):

> Sun Mar 29 10:25:29 EDT 2015

I need to convert it to a `date` datatype like this format:

> 04/29/2015

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Convert TIMESTAMP with Timezone to DATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089859/oracle-convert-timestamp-with-timezone-to-date)

Comment: Thanks allot for the answers, That solved my issue!! it works fine with my query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/SQL is not required. First use `to_timestamp_tz` to convert the string into Oracle `timestamp with time zone` data type. Then use `to_char` to convert the value of the data type into the textual presentation of your like:

```
-- edited for readability
SQL> select to_char(to_timestamp_tz('Sun Mar 29 10:25:29 EDT 2015',
                                    'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY'),
                    'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
03/29/2015

SQL>
```

Oracle documentation:

- [Datetime functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions002.htm#SQLRF20033)
- [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date strings keep to a rigid format suggested by your example, something like this could work:

```
declare
  s varchar2(32) := 'Sun Mar 29 10:25:29 EDT 2015';
  s_mdy varchar2(32);
  d date;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(s);
  s_mdy := substr(s,5,6) || substr(s,24);
  dbms_output.put_line(s_mdy);
  d := to_date(s_mdy, 'MON DD YYYY');
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(d, 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
end;
/
```

Output:

```
Sun Mar 29 10:25:29 EDT 2015
Mar 29 2015
03/29/2015
```

Comment: The above answers resolved my issue. Thanks for the suggestion, I  will try that as well.