# I want to convert this date format 1970-01-01T00:00:00-08:00 to only dd/mm/yyyy in oracle. But by using below query i'm getting error in conversion

Tags: oracle, date

I'm using this Query

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE('1970-01-01T00:00:00-08:00', 'T', ''), 
                                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') AS DATE) DOB FROM dual;
```

Output is

> ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12 01849. 00000 - "hour must be
>   between 1 and 12"

I need the output only as `MM/DD/YYYY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time format is 24 hours, so the fix is to use `HH24` instead of `HH`.

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    REPLACE('1970-01-01T00:00:00-08:00', 'T', ''),
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') AS DATE) DOB 
FROM dual;
```

But instead of using replace, you can use literal `"T"` in the pattern:

```
SELECT CAST(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1970-01-01T00:00:00-08:00', 
        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') 
    AS DATE) DOB FROM dual;
```

Be advised that the cast just drops the timezone info. If you need to convert the timestamps to date at a particular timezone (say +04:00), use `at time zone` clause on `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```
SELECT CAST(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1970-01-01T00:00:00-08:00', 
        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') 
    at time zone '+04:00' AS DATE) DOB FROM dual;
```

See more at:

- [Oracle Convert TIMESTAMP with Timezone to DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089859/oracle-convert-timestamp-with-timezone-to-date)

---

Since you want output in format `MM/DD/YYYY`, use to_char on the timestamp directly:

```
SELECT to_char(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1970-01-01T00:00:00-08:00', 
        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') 
    at time zone '+04:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY') DOB FROM dual;
```